# How to mock trait in benchmarking

Tags: benchmarking, mock

Can you tell me how to mock a `trait` in `benchmarking`?

We have a pallet which takes NFTTrait as one of the configs. See below.

```
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
        /// NFT Handler
        type NFTHandler: NFTTrait<Self::AccountId, ClassId = ClassId, TokenId = TokenId>;
    }
```

In the mock, we have created a struct to mock NFTTrait and pass it to the config.

```
pub struct NFTHandler;

impl NFTTrait<u128> for NFTHandler {
   fn check_ownership(who: &AccountId, asset_id: &Self::AssetId) -> Result<bool>;
}

impl Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type NFTHandler = NFTHandler;
}
```

So how do I achieve the same thing in benchmarking? I tried to
add `use crate::mock::NFTHandler;` on top of benchmarking class. Although IDE can find the correct reference, it did give me an error when I built it.

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::mock`
  --> pallets/marketplace/src/benchmarking.rs:34:12
   |
34 | use crate::mock::NFTHandler;
   |            ^^^^ could not find `mock` in the crate root
```

Below is a snippet from benchmarking file

```
#![cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]

use super::*;
use sp_std::prelude::*;
use sp_std::vec;

#[allow(unused)]
use crate::*;
use frame_benchmarking::{account, benchmarks, impl_benchmark_test_suite, whitelisted_caller};
use frame_support::traits::{Currency, Get};
use frame_system::RawOrigin;
use pallet_nft::{Attributes, CollectionType, TokenType};
use sp_runtime::traits::{AccountIdConversion, StaticLookup, UniqueSaturatedInto};
use crate::{Call, Config};
use crate::mock::NFTHandler;


const SEED: u32 = 0;
pub type AccountId = u128;
pub type AssetId = u128;

const ALICE: AccountId = 1;
const NFT_ID: AssetId = 99;

fn mint_NFT<T: Config>(caller: T::AccountId) {
    NFTModule::<T>::mint(
        RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()).into(),
        ALICE,
        test_attributes(1)      
    );
}

benchmarks! {   
    list_item{
        let caller: T::AccountId = account('caller', 0, SEED);

        mint_NFT::<T>(caller.clone());
    }: _(RawOrigin::Signed(caller.clone()), NFT_ID)
    verify {
        let listing_id = crate::Pallet::<T>::get_listing_item(NFT_ID);
        assert_eq!(listing_id, 0);
    }
}

impl_benchmark_test_suite!(Pallet, crate::benchmarking::tests::new_test_ext(), crate::mock::Test);
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks

Comment: You are going to need to share the code in your benchmarking file.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnTabrizi, could you provide an example or code snippet?

Comment: Why are you asking me to share code? You are showing an error, but not showing the code which got you to this error. You need to provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry @ShawnTabrizi, my bad, wasn't thinking. I thought you were suggesting code sharing between mock and benchmarking file. Anyway, I have add a code snippet of our benchmarking file. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for making this an answer; it won't let me comment without 50 rep first :/ We're trying to do the exact thing above, however, the benchmarks are calling the runtime config version and not the mock config version of the trait implementation, and I can't figure out why. The mock pallet config is set to use `T::AccountHandler`, defined inside mock.rs, for a defined `AccountProvider` trait. mock.rs:
```
pub struct AccountHandler;
impl AccountProvider<AccountId, BlockNumber> for AccountHandler { fn get_msa_id(key: &AccountId) -> Option<MessageSenderId> { // etc. }
}
impl pallet_messages::Conf

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your `mock` is only accessible when compiling with the `test` flag, like so:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod mock;
```

So if you want to use this dependency, you must do so with this feature gate:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
use crate::mock::NFTHandler;
```

And note that you cannot really write any non-test code which uses this dependency since it wont compile when you actually want to run benchmarks.

Instead, you probably DON'T want to import `struct NFTHandler`, but instead use your trait:

```rust
T::NFTHandler::check_ownership(...)
```

Which should require no imports from `mock`.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I suppose `T::NFTHandler::check_ownership(...)` will be calling the things I put inside mock file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it will call however you implement your runtime. So for tests, it will call the `mock`, but then when doing REAL benchmarks, it will call the real implementation. That is the flexibility of Rust and Substrate.

Comment: Thank you @shawn-tabrizi

Comment: Hi Shawn,  in the benchmarking file, how did you reference another pallet that defined in the runtime?