# How can I access the emitted runtime events inside the benchmarking.rs file?

Tags: benchmarking

I read in [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/how-to-mock-trait-in-benchmarking) that you can access everything from mock runtime in the benchmarking file by just adding `#[cfg(test)]` above the import `use crate::mock::*;` and that it is not a good idea since it only applies when running benchmark tests and not during the actual benchmarking against the real runtime.

In my case, I need to deploy a smart contract, get its address from the events emitted and then use that to benchmark a `Pallet::<T>::transfer(to, erc20_address, amount)` function. How can I access the `Systems::events()` inside the benchmark file? Thanks.

Edit: [This solution](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/5101/3217) worked for getting all the events emitted by the `frame_system` pallet. However, I need to match the contract instantiation event with all the events returned from the `frame_system::Pallet::<T>::events()` to extract the deployed contract code. I defined an `Event = <T as frame_system::Config>::Event` but it gave the error --

```
let Event = <T as frame_system::Config>::Event;
   |         ----- help: `Event` is defined here, but is not a type
...
60 |             if let Event::Contracts(pallet_contracts::Event::Instantiated {
   |                    ^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Event`

error[E0575]: expected method or associated constant, found associated type `frame_system::Config::Event`
```

I've added the code snippet for more context below:

```
    let evts = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::events();
    let Event = <T as frame_system::Config>::Event; // This line doesn't work
    let deployed = evts
        .iter()
        .rev()
        .find_map(|rec| {
            if let Event::Contracts(pallet_contracts::Event::Instantiated {
                deployer: _,
                contract,
            }) = &rec.event
            {
                Some(contract)
            } else {
                None
            }
        })
        .expect("unable to find deployed contract");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access the events. For example like this:

```rust
benchmarks! {
    something {
        assert!(frame_system::Pallet::<T>::events().is_empty());
    }: _(…)
    verify {
        assert!(!frame_system::Pallet::<T>::events().is_empty());
    }
```

One gotcha here is to initialize the block number in your `new_test_ext` functions. Otherwise the event emission does not work:

```rust
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    let mut ext = sp_io::TestExternalities::new(t);
    ext.execute_with(|| System::set_block_number(1));
    ext
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you please check my recent edit to the question? I need help on just one more thing.

Comment: what about `if let pallet_contracts::Event::Instantiated { .. }`

Comment: Please paste it into a new question - in case Daan's comment did not answer it. Otherwise it is not as helpful to others who may come across the same hardship.